# VBA Excel macro stopped seeing textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in excel that used to work fine for a few days but today when I launch it's not working anymore. Funny thing is that no changes were made to the excel file nor the macro.

The macro is attached to a button and gets data from a TextBox named `CSVExportRange`. When I try to launch it I get an

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

error in the line where I set Range based on value of the textfield:

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range(Application.ActiveSheet.CSVExportRange.Value)
```

I tried experimenting with it and it turns out it doesn't see the TextBox at all now:

```
Dim a As Worksheet
Dim k As TextBox
       
Set a = Application.ActiveSheet
Set k = Application.ActiveSheet.CSVExportRange
```

In the above case debug breaks at the last line with "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

I have the TextBox setup properly and didn't change it since last time everything worked fine.

[image: screen]

What's wrong?

Comment: The screenshot shows `CSVExportPath`, not `CSVExportRange`.

Comment: You're right, I must have moved scroll on mouse when doing the screen and the selection changed.
CSVExportRange is set in the same way (I would have added a new screenshot but I can't edit my post nor add it in the comment here).

Comment: Does the value from csvexportrange exist as a string range (ex: "$a$1") ? And not empty? How do you populate csvexportrange ?

Comment: You should exchange `.ActiveSheet.` with the actual sheet name.

Comment: @ PatrickLepelletier
Yes it's a valid range ("A1:A100"). Value is entered by user.

@ UGP
I'm using ActiveSheet as this macro is intended to be used in any sheet in any file (it's an add-in) and it's always launched by a button existing in given sheet so active sheet will always be ser properly.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why it happened but restarting Excel twice helped... 
Like, when I closed all Excel files and relaunched it, it was not working still. After doing so once more it started working again.

Note that neither is a remote / network / shared file so it's not a case of someone / something else locking some file...

Comment: Then probably before the restart the wrong sheet was the `ActiveSheet`. Using `ActiveSheet` produces odd issues in most cases because people use it wrong. I hardly recommend to avoid using `ActiveSheet` instead always specify the sheet exactly by its name `Worksheets("MySheetName")` so the macro always refers to the correct sheet independent from which sheet is active at the moment. Also see [VBA Best Practices: Avoid using ActiveCell or ActiveSheet in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/7264/avoid-using-activecell-or-activesheet-in-excel).